# Can you really tell the relationship between mean and median in a skewed graph?

Tags: statistics

In two old statistics textbooks, I found the following pictures:-
[image: graphs of distributions]
Without any explanation, they both inferred the following:-

When it is right skewed (as in fig. 3.2), mean > median. (And is the otherwise for the left skewed.)

1. I wonder if the claim is always true?
2. If it is, is there any simple proof? [By simple, I mean something like by inspection or simple logical reasoning but not deep into the statistical theory please.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof isn't quite right. Step 3 is a new assumption that doesn't follow from anything before. The mean-median=mode inequality is true for "nice" distributions, but you have to define nice more carefully than this proof does. The author gives the Gaussian as an example of a nice distribution, but the Gaussian has no skew. You might think the Weibull is a nice distribution, but the inequality doesn't hold for the Weibull.

Thee following article has a good discussion of violations, with citations that clarify the conditions under which the inequality is true.

- Paul T. von Hippel. (2005). Mean, Median, and Skew: Correcting a Textbook Rule. *Journal of Statistics Education*, Volume 13, Number 2, jse.amstat.org/v13n2/vonhippel.html

Answer (score 1):

This claim is false.  Here's an interesting article on the subject: [Mean, Median, and Skew: Correcting a Textbook Rule](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n2/vonhippel.html)

Also note that you shouldn't confuse the terms [skew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) with [nonparametric skew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew), for which your claim is true by definition.

Comment: The link given provides a very good reference. A similar comment was just found in wikipedia (but not in that detail). It mentions that before 2005, there was indeed such a claim. It was later "proved" to be untrue especially for surprising frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

While you have been given an answer that this is not always true, it is still true for some *nice* distributions, and one way to *prove* it by simple inspection is the following.

1. The median $\nu$ means that the area under the distribution curve is equal at each side. $$\int_{-\infty}^\nu f(x)dx=\int_\nu^\infty f(x)dx$$
2. When the graphic is skewed, the mood $\theta$ is in one of the sides and the graphic is overall taller at that side.  **Note:** this is for *nice* gaussian-like distributions, distributions with irregularities or several peeks will not behave the same.

   Without loss of generalization let's say that $\theta>\nu$.
3. So the mean $\mu_+$ in the taller side, is closer to the median than the mean $\mu_-$ in the shorter side: \begin{align}\mu_--\nu&=\int_{-\infty}^\nu(x-\nu)f(x)dx\\\mu_+-\nu&=\int_\nu^\infty(x-\nu)f(x)dx\end{align} So $\nu-\mu_->\mu_+-\nu$
4. As the distribution have the same area, at each side of the median $\nu$, the overall mean $\mu$ is the arithmetic mean of $\mu_-$ and $\mu_+$.  From the above we have:\begin{align}\nu-\mu_-&>\mu_+-\nu\\2\nu&>\mu_++\mu_-\\ \nu&>\frac{\mu_++\mu_-}{2}=\mu\end{align}
5. So the mean $\mu$ is at the other side of the median $\nu$ than the mood $\theta$, either $\mu<\nu<\theta$ or $\theta<\nu<\mu$.

I hope this is what you were asking, and beware that not all distributions behave like this.

Comment: Eugenio Thomps That is a very good derivation. This is true only when the “distribution” is “nice” and smooth and without any surprising frequencies especially at the end(s). Right?